# Sorting a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am having an issue of a Null pointer exception. As much as i try i can't find any sort of help. If someone has an idea please let me know.

```
for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link) {

    k = addScore(cursor.num);
    for (int i = 1; i <= nodeLength(); i++) {

        cursorAdd = head.link;
        j = addScore(cursorAdd.num);

        if (j > k) {

            cursor.link = cursorAdd.link;
            cursorAdd.link = cursor;
        }
        cursorAdd = cursorAdd.link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Homework I assume?  Because otherwise there's a very nice `LinkedList` that comes with Java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: what if `cursorAdd` is `null`?

Comment: Have a look at the stack trace, it shows in which line there is the exception. Look at this line, which variables are used there? If this still does not help, show us the stacktrace and mark the corresponding line in your code.

Comment: Could it be because you are doing cursor.link=cusorAdd.link and then doing another cursor.link at the end of the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

You don't check that `cursorAdd != null` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your list has only one element. So

```
head != null
head.link == null;
cursor = head; // cursor != null; cursor.link == null.
cursorAdd = cursor.link; // == null
addScore(cursorAdd.num) <-- NPE
```